# How to create a SQL Merge Publication without creating BCP files

Tags: sql, merge, replication, bcp

I have a large database (250GB). We are copying the database to a new location (basically moving it from a customer site to a datacenter, linked via VPN), making it a publisher, and the original database will become the subscriber.

We have an identical database that is 2GB and we are using this to test the replication. The process I am going through is

1) Backup the database at the original location
2) Restore the database at the new location
3) Create a publication at the new location
4) Create a subscription at the old location pointing at the new publisher with nosync (because I already have the data, and I don't want to initialise the subscriber again)

This all works fine and is replicating nicely. My issue is the BCP files. For the 2GB database, it has created 2GB of snapshot (mainly BCP) files. In my new location, the disk storage is SAN, and is very expensive. I don't want to have to buy an extra 250GB of space to accommodate 250GB of BCP files that I'll never use.

Is there any way to make the publication without the BCP files? Or is this a fundamental part of replication I can't get away from?

Thanks in advance for your help.
-Nick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately even when initializing a Merge subscription without a snapshot, a snapshot must still be generated.  Although the schema and data bcp files will not be used, the snapshot is required because it includes system objects and metadata required by replication.

Comment: Thanks Brandon. Quite annoying but I can understand why.

Comment: Just out of interest, I am solving this problem by manually synchronising the data in the tables with the large columns (i.e. inserting into a SyncLog table using triggers on update/insert/delete) and a console application that runs on a schedule and updates the databases at either end. Seems like I'm going backwards in time to before replication existed! It's either that, or I have to spend £3,000 per year for space for the sake of it. Any thoughts on this appreciated.